# essage: OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Unspecified error SSAS and SSRS installed

Tags: reporting-services, ssas

got following error in msmdsrv.log.

> (01/04/2012 12:46:22) Message: OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error:
>   Unspecified error. (Source: \?\E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSAS10_50\OLAP\Log\msmdsrv.log, Type: 3, Category: 289, Event
>   ID: 0xC1210003)
>
> (01/04/2012 12:46:25) Message: OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error:
>   Unspecified error. (Source: \?\E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSAS10_50\OLAP\Log\msmdsrv.log, Type: 3, Category: 289, Event
>   ID: 0xC1210003)

and Application Log:

OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Unspecified error. EentID=3 and category=289.

How do i resolve this error?

This server has Ssas and reporting services installed...

Regards,

Manish

Answer (score 0):

By any chance are you running into a divide by zero error?  That is the DSV / view you are processing against ends up having a divide by zero calculation.  Best way to determine if this is happening is to turn on Profiler and record the SQL query being executed by SSAS against your data source. Then run that query directly against the DS (eg SSMS for SQL Server) to see the error message it delivers.